# Emacs 24.5 Won't Open (OS X)

Tags: emacs

I recently installed the latest version of Emacs (24.5) on OS X 10.10.3. I got one session out of it, but now when I try to open it from the Applications folder, it does not launch. Technically it does launch (black dot under the Emacs icon in the Dock at the bottom), but will not display a window or show in the status bar at the top, and the only way to close it is to right click the Dock icon and force quit. Curiously, it opens just fine if I select say an HTML file in Finder, right click, and open with Emacs. Any idea what could be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The Emacs icon in the docker should have a *New Frame* option; does that work?

Comment: Did you try running a clean emacs from the terminal? `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -q`

Comment: Sounds like maybe the icon in the dock isn't pointing to the right binary... perhaps remove the installation and reinstall?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the delay in responding. I'm in a rush on a web development project, so I just switched to a more web-oriented editor (Brackets) and gave up on Emacs troubleshooting for now. Will revisit in the future. Thanks for the inputs!